SQL Server 2019 Express Setup.exe not Installing SQL Server instance
I ran this command on the extracted SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe, which is the SQL Server 2019 x64 Express installer:
SETUP.EXE /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLEXPRESS 
          /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN /ENABLERANU=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="password" 
          /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE 
          /IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS /IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS

After running that command, the SQL Server instance MSSQLEXPRESS is not installed. I checked it with SSMS.
Does anybody know why?

Did you run SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe or SETUP.EXE?

I ran SETUP.EXE

You may need to set the SQL Server service to start automatically by adding the parameter /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE Automatic to make sure the service actually runs once the installation completes.
(Source)

This did not work. I also went to services.msc and set all SQL services to automatic, then rebooted. I noticed that if you uninstall SQL Server 2019 Express that the instance is there, but the instance does not show up with SSMS 20.

It turned out that SSMS 18 can see the SQL Instance! Is there anyway to configure SSMS 20 to see my SQL Instance although?

Note that I am having trouble reproducing this... I am still trying to get the instance to show up in SSMS 18 again... some how I got it to show up in SSMS 18...

It works when you run setup.exe as a GUI, but no matter what I do when I run setup.exe on the command line with /qs it does not work. I am stuck on this.

It turns out that I can connect to the instance in SSMS, but it is not discoverable. For what I am doing, I am doing an Install Shield project, I need it to be discoverable.

I added this: /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=AUTOMATIC and that did not work either.

It turns out that my instance shows up when you browse locally in SSMS. Is there anyway to get the instance to show up in the default list?
